# Django. How to restrict "profile" page to only "friends"

Tags: python, django

I currently have a "profile" page that displays specific users information they have uploaded. Currently it does so by

```
objects.filter(user = request.user)
```

Im trying to figure out how I can allow a, for lack of a better description, a "friend" to view someone else's profile. Cause right now, the user who makes the request gets their own information. I believe I know how to build the ability to "friend" another user... i just dont know how to display another users info since all ive been filtering on so far is "request.user"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

You object should look like this

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(Profile)
```

To check whether target profile belongs to your friend you can modify your code following way:

```
Profile.objects.filter(friends = request.user)
```

Comment: I believe i understand the ManyToMany relationship for creating the "friends" but Im lost on how to display a different users profile to someone other and themselves.  I feel like its going to require using the users ID or PK somehow.... am i barking up the right tree?

Comment: You need to have 2 conditions. The profile should either belongs to the current user or has the current user as the friend. You already mentioned first condition and my previous comment contain the second one. All together it will looks like `Profile.objects.filter(Q(friends=request.user) | Q(pk=request.user_id))` (it will work in case if user is your profile model)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share how I implemented this in a project of mine. This may be somewhat specific for how I have implemented friend relationships, but I think the main idea should be the same.

Here is the view for `view_profile`

```
def view_profile(request, username):
    if request.user.username == username:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:profile'))
    #get the user we are looking at
    person = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    #get the userprofile
    person = person.userprofile
    person_friend_object, person_created = Friend.objects.get_or_create(current_user=person)
    user_friends = [friend for friend in person_friend_object.users.all()]
    follower_count = len(user_friends)

    friend = False

    context = {
        'person':person,
        'friend':friend,
        'follower_count':follower_count,
        'user_friends':user_friends,
    }

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        friend_object, created = Friend.objects.get_or_create(current_user=request.user.userprofile)
        friends = [friend for friend in friend_object.users.all()]
        if person in friends:
            friend = True
        else:
            friend = False

    context['friend'] = friend

    return render(request, 'users/user_profile_view.html', context)
```

Then, in the template you can control what friend can see of a given user's profile with template logic. Here's a basic example:

```
{% if not friend %}
<p>You are not friends with this user</p><button>Add friend</button>
{% else %}
<p>You are friends with this user. Here is information about this user...(here you can show data on the user through by accessing the `person` context variable)</p><button>Unfriend</button>
{% endif %}
```

So everything is controlled by the `friend` variable which is either True or False.

There are many ways to do what you are describing, this would be just one way I believe. Hope this helps with your project.